# Windows restore Emails Outlook 2007

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook, restore

The Harddrive of my Laptop crashed, so now i want to install a clean new copy of Windows Vista (on a new HDD ), i cant run the old System to make a Backup of the Mails like Outlook Help wants me to do, i only have a Bakup of the Files of the old System, so the files that Outlook stores it's Data in /Users/Me/AppData/Local/.. , how can i restore the Mails to the new Installation? Will it work if i just copy the old files to the new system?

Comment: The only way to restore your emails is to move the data file from your old hdd to your new hdd.  The physical location of this file depends on your specific configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you surmised, the basic steps involve moving Outlook's OSTs/PSTs over. The following articles are too long to quote/rewrite in their entirety, so I'm just going to provide links here:

- [Move an Outlook data file from one computer to another](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-an-outlook-data-file-from-one-computer-to-another-HA001230892.aspx)
- [Move Outlook information to another computer that has Outlook 2010 installed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-outlook-information-to-another-computer-that-has-outlook-2010-installed-HA102544948.aspx)

Comment: If someone wants to edit and add a précis of the articles, please feel free to do so.